# No vertical scroll in browser window when pop up goes outside of the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is the code of my test code

https://jsfiddle.net/wo58xseb/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, 
initial-scale=1">
<style>

    .popup {

   position: relative;
   display: inline-block;
   }


   .popup .popuptext {
  left:50%;
  top:200px;
  margin-left:-300px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto; 

   }
  .popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
  }

  * { box-sizing: border-box; }
  body {
     font: 16px Arial;

   }

   .button_add_name
  {
    display:block;
    margin-right:50%;
    margin-left:50%;
    margin-bottom:1%;
  }

    .button_add_tag
    {
       margin-bottom:1%;
    }

     </style>
    </head>
    <body style="text-align:center">

    <h2>Popup</h2>
    <div class="popup" >
    <button type="button" id = "5" 
    onclick="myFunction()">Add Tag</button>
      <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
    <button type="button" class = "button_add_name" id = 
    "6">TAG</button>
   <button class = "button_add_tag" style="background-color: 
    #f44336" type="button" id = "5" 
    onclick="myclose()">Add</button>
      </span>
    </div>

<div> This is main text</div>
<script>
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.onclick = "";
  if(!popup.classList.contains("show"))
  popup.classList.toggle("show");

  if(this.id == 5)
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}
function myclose() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

function add_items()
{
    var b = document.getElementById("myPopup");
    for(i = 0;i<600;++i)
    b.innerHTML += "<button class = \"button_add_tag\"         type=\"button\"  onclick=\"myclose()\">JS</button>";
}

add_items();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a simple popup window (div) when button is pressed. Then I fill it with buttons using java script.
The problem is that when popup is too large the browser window does not show vertical scroll bar. The popup goes below the window and bottom content of it is hidden.
I have searched the internet but most describe how to add scroll into popups window. I don't want that.
I need a vertical scroll bar in browser window when popup div goes outside the browser window.
How can I do that?

```js
// When the user clicks on div, open the popup
function myFunction() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.onclick = "";
  if (!popup.classList.contains("show"))
    popup.classList.toggle("show");

  if (this.id == 5)
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

function myclose() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
}

function add_items() {
  var b = document.getElementById("myPopup");
  for (i = 0; i < 600; ++i)
    b.innerHTML += "<button class = \"button_add_tag\" type=\"button\"  onclick=\"myclose()\">JS</button>";
}

add_items();
```

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.popup {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.popup .popuptext {
  left: 50%;
  top: 200px;
  margin-left: -300px;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 600px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #000000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 8px 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto;
}

.popup .show {
  visibility: visible;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font: 16px Arial;
}

.button_add_name {
  display: block;
  margin-right: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}

.button_add_tag {
  margin-bottom: 1%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>
<div class="popup">
  <button type="button" id="5" onclick="myFunction()">Add Tag</button>
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">
<button type="button" class = "button_add_name" id = "6">TAG</button>
  <button class = "button_add_tag" style="background-color: #f44336" type="button" id = "5" onclick="myclose()">Add</button>
  </span>
</div>

<div> This is main text</div>
```

Comment: Elements with `position: fixed` are not counted when height of the parent is calculated

Comment: Thanks for this important note. I have removed fixed position from my div's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have removed fixed attribute from the main div which holds popup content.
I changed it to absolute position.
The Java Script changes the attribute of the div from hidden to visible.
The browser takes the height of the div to account when calculating the height of
the whole page. And the scroll bar is shown correctly.
Interesting that vertical scroll bar is displayed even if the div is hidden.
But currently it is not a big problem for me.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of placing a scrollbar within the popup, it can also be done so that the popup itself will scroll on its own as a whole. The difference is shown well with [these examples by Material UI](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#scrolling-long-content)

### HTML

Implementing this as a general idea requires the following html structure:

```html
<body>
  <div class="backdrop">
    <div class="scroller">
      <div class="content">
        <p>This is the cool dialog! ...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <main>
    <h1>Cool Title</h1>
    <p>This is the main webpage content</p>
  </main>
</body>
```

### CSS

Then the backdrop is given `position: fixed`, the scroller is given `height: 100%; overflow: hidden auto;`, and the content is given `position: relative; overflow-y: auto;`

### CSS & JS

Finally, the pop-up should have `display: none` when not open, and when it is open, the body should switch to `overflow: hidden` so that the user cannot continue to scroll the body while the dialog is open.

### Polishing

Adding more styles for aesthetics and the JavaScript to handle opening and closing the dialog, we get this proof of concept...

[CodeSandox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-mendeleev-or05y9?file=/index.html)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<style>
    body {
        font-size: 2rem;
        margin: 0;
    }
    .colors {
        color: rgb(220,220,220);
        background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    .no-scroll {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .backdrop {
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 100;
        inset: 0px;
        display: block;
        background-color: rgba(150,150,150,0.5);
    }
    .hidden {
        display: none;
    }
    .scrollBody {
        height: 100%;
        outline: 0px;
        overflow: hidden auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .content {
        background-color: rgb(220,220,220);
        color: rgb(50,50,50);
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 20%) 0px 11px 15px -7px, rgb(0 0 0 / 14%) 0px 24px 38px 3px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 9px 46px 8px;
        margin: 32px;
        position: relative;
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: left;
        max-width: 600px;
        padding: 1rem;
    }
    input[type="button"] {
        padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>

<script>
    function openPopUp() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("backdrop")?.[0]?.classList?.remove("hidden");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")?.[0]?.classList?.add("no-scroll");
    }
    function closePopUp() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("backdrop")?.[0]?.classList.add("hidden");
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")?.[0]?.classList?.remove("no-scroll");
    }
</script>

<body>
    <div class="backdrop hidden" role="dialog" aria-modal="true">
        <div class="scrollBody">
            <div class="content">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sapiente ab ex ea nemo reiciendis saepe dicta distinctio porro? Nam consectetur suscipit veritatis nulla facilis nihil necessitatibus provident reiciendis quam sint.</p>
                <p>Cupiditate nisi repellat nulla voluptatibus quam deserunt quisquam consequatur assumenda quo possimus, reiciendis voluptas. Voluptatum quam, est omnis repellendus voluptate deleniti laborum voluptates pariatur debitis quaerat fuga dicta quis recusandae?</p>
                <p>Quibusdam aut minus omnis! Nostrum, architecto. Itaque error magni veniam incidunt iste nesciunt eius. Provident voluptates in porro, odio fugiat alias deserunt facilis a fuga inventore aspernatur. Recusandae, nihil distinctio!</p>
                <p>Recusandae eum culpa illo? Quo nemo quam veritatis molestiae reprehenderit perferendis, eaque placeat distinctio quae optio, aperiam hic, voluptate fugit illo beatae iure tempore saepe. Minima, labore? Rerum, provident incidunt!</p>
                <p>Fuga maxime repudiandae totam neque corrupti enim officia, corporis necessitatibus, inventore hic velit consectetur, earum asperiores cum deleniti! Corrupti consequuntur quo necessitatibus non pariatur deleniti a dolor sequi laudantium aliquam?</p>
                <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="closePopUp()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="colors">
        <input type="button" value="Open Pop-up" onclick="openPopUp()" />
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius corporis itaque laborum tenetur et est voluptates. Maxime corrupti a excepturi, id molestiae sapiente iure laborum! Quos quae quam perferendis quasi!</p>
        <p>Ratione impedit iure ab ipsa eum distinctio laboriosam aut quod neque. Consequuntur doloremque maiores, repudiandae, sit voluptate commodi quibusdam perferendis, praesentium inventore a ad rem non aspernatur hic atque quas!</p>
        <p>Ullam iure sint qui error, aut ducimus fugiat. Cupiditate eligendi quas nulla labore, nam, dolor culpa aliquam ad architecto dolorum saepe libero pariatur, illo unde qui hic vel! Aut, eum.</p>
        <p>Porro accusantium incidunt, libero quisquam quos maiores deserunt quas veniam nemo earum quo sit architecto at minus minima cum optio cumque voluptatem labore iure. Quibusdam quidem repudiandae autem cum eos.</p>
        <p>Doloribus mollitia, cum aliquid asperiores dolore a repudiandae eligendi sequi vel cupiditate impedit maxime vitae quisquam in cumque! Error necessitatibus, veritatis repellat a qui quas laudantium beatae magnam molestiae expedita?</p>
        <p>Aperiam architecto qui debitis molestiae libero, voluptatem eius maiores, vel praesentium nobis eaque temporibus odio pariatur molestias iure accusamus? Quibusdam, laborum. Nam, odit velit a similique fuga atque. Doloremque, labore!</p>
        <p>Eligendi veritatis, assumenda natus dolorum harum numquam ipsa blanditiis eaque libero aspernatur nulla incidunt pariatur inventore eum! At voluptatem odit quasi incidunt impedit quae expedita aliquid, nam facilis dicta velit?</p>
        <p>Delectus, dolore. Cumque commodi a voluptates eos, ad aperiam corporis asperiores accusantium, facere soluta, perferendis ipsam quam magni unde itaque iusto atque. Iste quibusdam adipisci nihil qui sint alias ipsum.</p>
        <p>Obcaecati unde beatae quo quis, architecto totam nobis id possimus odio fugiat reprehenderit iste eum eligendi. Ipsum rem assumenda voluptate iste nesciunt alias quos dicta eaque dignissimos. Perferendis, illo tenetur!</p>
        <p>Voluptate distinctio magni blanditiis voluptatem nulla ipsa provident, quod eligendi, veritatis sit velit quis magnam vitae explicabo debitis corrupti, dolor ad deserunt non quibusdam quia. Mollitia maiores quisquam provident vero.</p>
        <p>Aliquam recusandae quis soluta, ipsa expedita voluptas perferendis molestias a quibusdam voluptatum velit obcaecati nemo assumenda quae ipsam eaque odio repellat eum architecto non quam sit provident id! Dolore, iure.</p>
        <p>Quia dicta ipsa commodi deserunt, pariatur delectus reprehenderit nesciunt. Error, quod, repellendus voluptates sit quas corrupti molestiae ratione odit quasi corporis nesciunt rerum facere mollitia delectus laborum expedita assumenda fugiat.</p>
        <p>Saepe cum nemo tenetur dolore, voluptatem ipsum quidem ad voluptate, voluptatum similique sint maiores autem reiciendis quo repellat! Amet ipsam consequatur nesciunt laudantium quam quasi dignissimos sint ea eligendi deserunt.</p>
        <p>Corrupti architecto corporis obcaecati a quisquam deleniti unde mollitia eaque veniam voluptate, optio tempora eos voluptatem voluptatum est autem nesciunt magni laboriosam quidem, deserunt dicta? Cumque vitae esse facilis eos?</p>
        <p>Non saepe, commodi quis aspernatur ut culpa deserunt? Exercitationem quibusdam assumenda nihil officiis quam, obcaecati fuga est quos sequi sint! Nobis harum at ipsa suscipit voluptas totam deleniti impedit molestiae?</p>
        <p>Nesciunt, sapiente? Corporis adipisci neque dolores dolor blanditiis, ducimus alias eum quis, dignissimos reiciendis architecto esse suscipit at. Aut quibusdam omnis rem. Aperiam molestias ut, distinctio cupiditate explicabo molestiae aliquam.</p>
        <p>Quas modi voluptas adipisci atque, magnam beatae voluptates totam, ipsa labore laboriosam a. Provident qui corporis ea nobis nostrum ducimus, odit, repellat quia illum excepturi voluptate officia? Excepturi, officiis voluptatum?</p>
        <p>Magnam, temporibus officiis. Consectetur dolor quibusdam deserunt rerum sed officia incidunt quo ea magni nobis mollitia autem harum animi quaerat consequuntur laudantium, asperiores cum fuga beatae nihil neque explicabo nesciunt?</p>
        <p>Illum delectus culpa laudantium atque sit, facilis quia molestias laborum dolor aliquam saepe error quo, in repellat voluptatibus harum, a ducimus perspiciatis ad. Eos totam qui labore sit hic eaque.</p>
        <p>Quasi, provident vel. Nemo facere minima aut repellat, perferendis officiis perspiciatis ratione? Esse dolorum provident, dolorem ipsa quod atque eius voluptate tempora ducimus quas omnis eos eveniet voluptatibus nisi et!</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, this example uses a bit different approach. I will study it